# troubles when getting information from dir - (php)

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$flags=FileSystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | FileSystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS;
$ul = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__."/../",$flags);
// $ul = new FileSystemIterator("/../",$flags);
foreach($ul as $file){
    if($file->isDir()){
        print $file->getFilename()."<br />";
    }
}
```

Its **DIR** is /var/www/html/dir1/dir2/dir3/test.php

It shows as the result of command : `ls /var/www/html/dir1/dir2/`

replace `$ul = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__."/../",$flags);` 
with `$ul = new FileSystemIterator("/../",$flags);`

It shows as the result of command : `ls /var/www/html/dir1/`
Why the second show happen?

Comment: `var_dump(__DIR__."/../", realpath(__DIR__."/../"), "/../", realpath("/../"));`  should show the difference between them?

Comment: It did show the difference between them . But i am confused with why such difference happen?What is defaultly before '/../'?

Comment: '/../' means start at the 'root' there is nothing before that so the `dotdot` is ignored. it just points to the same directory rather than the parent. Or the filesystem treats it as special case. The result is the same.